# Find species from FASTA files

Tags: fasta, blast, taxonomy, homework

In a school project we got the task of finding the species from two FASTA files. We got some hints of what to look for, like it is a unicellular eukaryote and that we can use blast. We don't know if the two files are the same species.

So I wonder if there is a standard way of finding species from FASTA files using the terminal?

I have a background in informatics, so I'm not well known with bioinformatics tools.

Answer (score 2):

Are you not allowed to use the [web BLAST tool](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PAGE=MegaBlast&PROGRAM=blastn&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch)? That's what I use if I need to quickly find out the likely origin of a DNA sequence.

There are command-line ways to do the same thing, but I only use them if I need to search hundreds or thousands of sequences at once.